# LRM-00111 Error importing an Oracle 12 DB

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, datapump, impdp

I want to import a Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production hosted in a Windows Server 12 R2, but I got this error:

```
LRM-00111: no closing quote for value ' schemas=O'
```

for all these commands

```
impdp SOLVIA/SOLVIA900@IMMBO DIRECTORY=DB_EXP DUMPFILE=week_exp_immbo.dmp LOGFILE=week_exp_immbo.log REUSE_DATAFILES=YES exclude=tablespace:\"IN (\'IMMBO\')\" schemas=SOLVIA

impdp SOLVIA/SOLVIA900@IMMBO DIRECTORY=DB_EXP DUMPFILE=week_exp_immbo.dmp LOGFILE=week_exp_immbo.log REUSE_DATAFILES=YES exclude=tablespace:\"IN (\'IMMBO\')\" "schemas=SOLVIA"

impdp SOLVIA/SOLVIA900@IMMBO DIRECTORY=DB_EXP DUMPFILE=week_exp_immbo.dmp LOGFILE=week_exp_immbo.log REUSE_DATAFILES=YES exclude=tablespace:\"IN (\'IMMBO\')\" schemas="SOLVIA"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use a parameter file; doing so, you'd avoid use of escape characters. For example, let's call it `PARAMS.PAR`:

```
directory=db_exp 
dumpfile=week_exp_immbo.dmp 
logfile=week_exp_immbo.log 
reuse_datafiles=yes 
exclude=tablespace: "IN ('IMMBO')"
schemas=solvia
```

Then, import data using

```
impdp solvia/solvia900@immbo parfile=params.par
```